# How can I initialize a dynamic size for my linked list with text file line count?

Tags: c++, file-io

I want to use lineCount for pLists[lineCount] instead of pLists[10000]
And how can I get the line count only open the file once and without vector?

```
ifstream ifs(inputFileName);
string line="";

DlinkedList* pLists[10000];

//get line input from file to lists
while (getline(ifs, line)){
    for (int count=0;getline(ifs, line); count++) {
        //input string to Dlists
        pLists[count] = new DlinkedList(line,digitsPerNode);
        cout << "Lists" << count << ":";
        pLists[count]->printList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: I can not use vector for my practice. Other possible idea?

Comment: what can you use? can you use other container in std namespace?

Comment: About the only way to get a count before initializing the array, is to read the file, get the count, reset the stream to the beginning, initialize the array and read the file all over again to fill the array.  You might be better off, just keeping track of the count and passing that as the size with the array, whenever you pass it to a function.

Comment: Just no std::vector

Comment: If you're not *allowed* to use a standard container in any form or way, create your own "vector"? Or linked list? Or other dynamic container? That is probably beyond the scope of your exercise so it would be pretty stupid, but some teachers might be strict that way. Or as suggested by @tinstaafl do two passes over the file, one to count the number of lines and another to read the contents.

Comment: It seems that you want to use doubly-linked list? So how about std::list?

Comment: The point of the list is to not need an array to save all the elements in. You have only the head element and every list element contains a pointer to the next one. That is why you wont need the linecount beforehand. Just read a line, create new node and set the pointer of the last element in the list to the new node.